# Phone: 15.4 update to Build 107 => no media player

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, media, mplayer

I've got the Meizu MX4 :) and 15.04 OS-Build 107 (armhf 20150908-020305). The media player is no longer available in the Ubuntu Store, before with 15.04 rc3 it worked....

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

media player is installed but does not appear under Applications

When you download a video (e.g. .3gp) it is saved in the video directory

to start from there does not work

just copied it to the archive "com.ubuntu.camera" within the video archive

it appears now in the galery and you can open it with the media player

as media player does not appear in the application overview I just sticked it to the side bar;)